# Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError when running my python program on os startup using systemd

Tags: python-3.x, systemd

- Basic background info:

  I'm trying to run my program on os startup (my current OS is Debian 9 
  latest stable release)
  my project is listening to the keyboard using Xlib library and I'm also 
  using Tkinter to pop up some UI windows.
- this is /etc/system/system/my_project.service

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Daemon tool that opens the required environment given a 
> certain shortcut key
>
> [Service]
> Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
> ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/keyboard_listener.py
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

- after reboot I run:
  `sudo systemctl status my_project.service`
  and I get the following error

> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py",
>   line 90, in **init**
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**     self.socket =
>   connect.get_socket(name, protocol, host, displayno)
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line
>   87, in get_socket
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**     return
>   mod.get_socket(dname, protocol, host, dno)
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py",
>   line 113, in get_socket
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**     raise
>   error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian keyboard_listener.py[303]:**
>   Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0":
>   [Errno 111] Connection refused
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian systemd[1]:** my_project.service: Main
>   process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian systemd[1]:** my_project.service: Unit
>   entered failed state.
>
> **May 08 11:49:43 debian systemd[1]:** my_project.service: Failed
>   with result 'exit-code'.

how can I solve this issue(Erron 111)? should I add something to my_project.service
and how can I make my project to run on startup?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr: `systemd` won't work

In absence of explicit ordering dependencies, `systemd` processes all units in a transaction simultaneously. That means it does not and will not wait for X server to become available on display :0 before starting your `.service` unit.

In modern GNU/Linux distributions, X server is not started directly by any systemd unit, so you cannot specify a systemd ordering dependency on X server. Hence `systemd` is not suitable for whatever you are trying to accomplish, at least not until more fine-grained dependency mechanisms are implemented in systemd.

## suggested workarounds

As a workaround, you may try `/etc/xdg/autostart`, `~/.config/autostart` or `~/.xinitrc` (whatever is applicable for your X.org setup). These scripts are guaranteed to be run from inside a *graphical* user session.

If status monitoring is desired, you can combine both methods and start a transient systemd unit with [`systemd-run`(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html) or equivalent from inside one of those scripts.

Comment: so, from your point of view, what is suitable for running an application (that depends on Xlib) at os startup?

Comment: @Guy expanded answer